# Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings' visual studio code

Tags: python-3.x

recently my system crashed and I had to move my Django project from c drive of old system to new. But after installing python,  visual studio and moving files, I am getting attached error. Seems it has something to do with env variables but I am not able to figure out how to solve it. Python is installed on "C:\Program Files\Python39"[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, the causes of this error is that Python is not configured in your virtual environment(my_env). Means that no Python path is given to be used in your virtual environment. Yo can easily solve this by the following steps

1. Deactivate your virtual environment. For Windows, the command is deactivate
2. Configure the path of your Python.
   virtualenv --python C:\Users\MoTech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe kye

note C:\Users\MoTech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe is the path of your Python and kye is the name of virtual environment. For your case put the Python path and name of your virtual environment.

3. Activate your virtual environment and everything will be okay.

Thanks, solution provided is for Windows operating system but for other OS the logic and steps are almost the same.

[image: For more clarity check this image]